# How to make number Count in loop in c#?

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop, while-loop, console-application

This is a simple begginer program with setter and getter concept
now i have to make it to first enter user name and password to get welcomed
and IF I ENTER WRONG INFO IT SHOULD DISPLAY INVALID AND 5 TRIES LEFT THEN if i again enter wrong info it should display 4 tries left and so on and finally when all tries are over it should hang the program or lock the screen or so

```
using System;


namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            demo obj = new demo();
            string uname, pass;
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        label1:
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter username");
            uname = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Password");
            pass = Console.ReadLine();
            obj.setName(uname);
            obj.setPass(pass);
            if (obj.getName() == "niit")
            {
                if (obj.getPass() == "1234")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("welcome");

                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid");
                Console.WriteLine("\n \n \n To try again enter y");
                int n = 5;
                string yes = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (yes == "y")
                {
                    while (n >= 1)
                    {
                        Console.Write(n + " Tries left");
                        goto label1;
                        n = --n;
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
    class demo
    {
        private string name, pass;
        public void setName(string name)
        {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public string getName()
        {
            return name;
        }
        public void setPass(string pass)
        {
            this.pass = pass;
        }
        public string getPass()
        {
            return pass;
        }
    }
}
```

Please suggest a simple begginers code to make the loop work and make the count down

Comment: Never use `goto` in this way! You can do everything with `if`, `while`, `do ... while`, `for`, `switch` and `try ... catch...`

Answer (score 2):

A while loop should suffice. Using a boolean to detect successful password entry.
When entered, it will break out of the loop.
invalid attempts will decrement the AttemptsLeft int.
Note: I haven't tried this in Visual Studio, the logic should be sound, but I recommend debugging and stepping through it to test if it meets your criteria.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        demo obj = new demo();
        string uname, pass;
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
    label1:
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter username");
        uname = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Password");
       bool SuccessfulPassword = false;
       int AttemptsLeft = 5;
        while(!SuccessfulPassword && AttemptsLeft > 0){
        pass = Console.ReadLine();
        obj.setName(uname);
        obj.setPass(pass);
        if (obj.getName() == "niit")
        {
            if (obj.getPass() == "1234")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("welcome");
                SuccessfulPassword = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            AttemptsLeft--;
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid");
            Console.WriteLine("\n \n \n To try again enter y");
            int n = 5;
            string yes = Console.ReadLine();
                if (yes == "y")
            {

                    Console.Write(AttemptsLeft + " Tries left");
            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This approach won't work because what happens when you write a successful username and get the password wrong. You can't count for that attempt being wrong since there is no else statement. Keethri and PLC beginner are the only ones that addressed that issue with logic

Answer (score 1):

try this updated main method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            demo obj = new demo();
            int n = 5;
            string uname, pass;
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            //Console.Clear();
        label1:
            Console.WriteLine("\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Enter username");
            uname = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Password");
            pass = Console.ReadLine();
            obj.setName(uname);
            obj.setPass(pass);
            if (obj.getName() == "niit" && obj.getPass() == "1234")
            {
                    Console.WriteLine("welcome");
            }
            else
            {
                //Console.Clear();
                if (n < 1)
                {
                    //Add ur screenlock n hang prog code 
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("ScreenLock");
                }
                else
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("\n Invalid");
                    Console.WriteLine("\n To try again enter y");
                    string yes = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("\n");
                    if (yes == "y")
                    {
                        while (n >= 1)
                        {
                            Console.Write(n + " Tries left");
                            n = --n;
                            goto label1;


                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.ReadKey();

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        demo obj = new demo();
        string uname, pass;
        boolean successful = false;
        int32 tries = 5;
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
    label1:
        Do 
        {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter username");
        uname = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Password");
        pass = Console.ReadLine();
        obj.setName(uname);
        obj.setPass(pass);
        if (obj.getName() == "niit")
        {
            if (obj.getPass() == "1234")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("welcome");
                successful = true;
            }
        }
        if (!successful)
        {
            tries--;
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid");
            if (tries > 1)
            { 
               Console.WriteLine("Have " + tries + " attempts left");
            }
            ElseIf (tries == 1)
            {
               Console.WriteLine("Have only one more attempt left");
            }
            Else
            {
               Console.WriteLine("Maximum number of tries exceed");
               Console.WriteLine("Goodbye");
            }
        }
        } While(!successful && Tries > 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you get the wrong input, you remaking your count `int n = 5;`
so everytime you have 5 tries left.

What you can do is  to declare your count outside of the `static void Main(string args[])` method

just like:

```
int n =5;
static void Main(string args[])
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you problems are the following nested `if`-contitions

```
if (obj.getName() == "niit")
{
    if (obj.getPass() == "1234")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("welcome");
    }
}
else
{
\\...
}
```

If the username is correct and the pass not, it wont enter the else branch.
a better solution to ask for input until it is valid id a `do ... while` loop
Following example has a lot of improvements over yours.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    demo obj = new demo();
    string uname, pass;
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
    int maxTries;
    int tries = maxTries = 5;
    do
    {
        if (tries != maxTries)//second and more
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid");
            Console.Write("\n\t" + tries + " Tries left");
            Console.WriteLine("\n\n\n\tTry again? (y/n)");
            string input;
            do
            {
                input = Console.ReadLine();
            } while (input != "y" && input != "n");

            if (input == "n")
            {
                return; // exit the program
            }
        }

        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter username");
        uname = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Password");
        pass = Console.ReadLine();
        obj.setName(uname);
        obj.setPass(pass);
        tries--;
    } while (obj.getName() != "niit" || obj.getPass() != "1234");
    Console.WriteLine("Wellcome");
}
```

PS: Classes should start with a capital letter.

`goto` is a relict of old times, it will mess with your programm structure and make things more complicated than they are. The only propper use i know is for fallthrough in switches, which also is needed only in rare cases.

A madeup one would be:

```
string vehicleType = "car";
switch(vehicleType)
{
    case "truck":
        Console.WriteLine("two wheeles and");
        goto case "car";
    case "car":
        Console.WriteLine("two wheeles and");
        goto case "motor cycle";
    case "motor cycle":
        Console.WriteLine("two wheeles");
        break;
    case "boat":
        Console.WriteLine("no wheeles");
        break;
}
```